# Solve for $x$ :- $(\sqrt{3x^2+6x+7} + \sqrt{5x^2+10x+4}) = 4-2x-x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The main question is :-

Solve for $x$ :-
$$(\sqrt{3x^2+6x+7} + \sqrt{5x^2+10x+4}) = 4-2x-x^2$$

My approach :-

For convenience, I assume 
$$t_1=3x^2+6x+7$$
$$t_2=5x^2+10x+4$$

Then, by rationalizing, we get,

$$\frac{t_1-t_2}{\sqrt{t_1}-\sqrt{t_2}}=4-2x-x^2$$
Which, when simplified, gives,

$$\frac{2x^2+4x-3}{\sqrt{t_1}-\sqrt{t_2}}=x^2+2x-4$$

I can't go any further. A hint shall be sufficient. Thanks!

EDIT : I have tried squaring and getting rid of the radical root, but trust me it's not worth it IMO. I'd appreciate some other, quicker method if you have any.

Comment: This should be a trivial problem if you just square the equality, simplify, and then square again to remove the middle term, i.e. $t_1+2\sqrt{t_1t_2}+t_2=(4-2x-2x^2)^2$, simplify with the radical alone on one side, and then square again.

Comment: That leaves me with a 8-power polynomial, which for a young brain like mine is tough.

Comment: Exactly, I think it you should try looking that the LHS is always positive but RHS is not

Comment: @Weijie, are you saying that I put the RHS positive and solve for $x$ via inequalities? I guess that would work, but how would you find out other answers if there were any? How will you even say that $RHS>0$ will give us the desired result and not something incomplete?

Comment: @AksharGandhi I think that you are not going very far with my idea. Since it just guives you a range of where the solution can be. Not all polynomial equations can be solved by hand, so if you could tell me were is the problem from it would help.

Comment: @AksharGandhi If this is an IMO problem I would try using some trigonometric substitution.

Comment: It's not a IMO problem, it's an olympiad-level problem. I do know that olympoad-level question require some hit-and-trial. I would really appreciate if ypu could combine all your thoughts into an answer.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, numerically there are solutions: -0.1196313.., -1.4821968

Comment: Wow...What are they equivalent to in fractions, or surds?

Comment: Don't know. I justed took the the (numerical) roots of the previously mentioned 8th order polynomial and verified that two of them solves the original problem.

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone could give me a complete answer, even if it's incomplete or wrong. Just tell me something becayse I'm frustrated now.

Comment: If it is not a contests problem trust me that it probably don't have a known way to represent the root, so try this with some approaching methods such has Newton's or Horner's

Comment: Newton gave expanations to find roots? Damn is there any area he did not push his nose into. @Weijie Chen, I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: Where'd the $2$ on the $-x^2$ go after rationalizing?  Also, I agree with @WeijieChen about using numerical methods.  [WolframAlpha also doesn't have a nice representation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(3x%5E2+%2B+6x+%2B+7)+%2B+sqrt(5x%5E2+%2B+10x+%2B+4)+%3D+4+-+2x+-+2x%5E2) of the answers.  On the other hand, have you tried completing the squares?  I started to but hit a wall pretty quickly.  But I thought it was interesting that both expressions under the radicals have $(x+1)^2$ when the square is completed.

Comment: I'm sorry @tilper, there was never any -2 in the coefficient of $x^2$. Also I didn't quite understand what did you say about the expressions under the radicals having $(x+1)^2$

Comment: That's even more interesting then for  two reasons:  (1) I already tried the fixed equation in WolframAlpha and it just sat there processing apparently indefinitely, and (2) Now the RHS also has $(x+1)^2$ after completing the square.

Comment: @AksharGandhi Can you tell me the source of question ?

Comment: My professor for my Regional Mathematics Olympiad preparation. Im assuming your Indian, so you must know about the olympiad

Comment: @AksharGandhi Test is made  by taking care of feasibility of doing question , they don't just put anything which is very difficult to solve .

Comment: This question is not from a test, my professor gave it to us as a challenge question. I thought about this question, then posted it. Are you happy now?

Comment: @AksharGandhi Please post a answer which your professor will give whenever he discuss the question .

Comment: Sure, I will, I guess many of you are interested in knowing the answer! Keep thinking guys, maybe if we sleep on it we may get it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the equation to solve is

$$\sqrt{3x^2+6x+7}+\sqrt{5x^2+10x+4}=4-2x-x^2$$

then, as others have noted, the main simplification to make is to complete all the squares, rewriting the equation as

$$\sqrt{3(x+1)^2+4}+\sqrt{5(x+1)^2-1}=5-(x+1)^2$$

at which point we can let $t=(x+1)^2$ and obtain the simpler-looking equation

$$\sqrt{3t+4}+\sqrt{5t-1}=5-t$$

Before doing any more algebra, note that that any real value of $t$ solving this last equation must satisfy ${1\over5}\le t\le 5$, since the left hand side acquires an imaginary part if $t\lt{1\over5}$, while the two sides have opposite signs if $t\gt5$.  Note also that the curve $y=\sqrt{3t+4}+\sqrt{5t-1}$ is strictly *increasing* for $t\ge{1\over5}$ while the line $y=5-t$ is strictly *decreasing*, so there can be at most one real solution $t$.  Finally, since 
$$\sqrt{{3\over5}+4}+\sqrt{{5\over5}-1}=\sqrt{{23\over5}}+0\lt\sqrt{45\over5}=3\lt5-{1\over5}$$

while

$$\sqrt{15+4}+\sqrt{25-1}\gt0=5-5$$

we can conclude there is *exactly one* real value of $t$ that solves the equation.  In fact we can see that ${1\over5}\lt t\lt1$ by noting that

$$\sqrt{3+4}+\sqrt{5-1}=\sqrt7+\sqrt4\gt\sqrt4+\sqrt4=4=5-1$$

> **A brief digression:**
>
> If the equation were
>
> $$\sqrt{3x^2+6x+7}+\sqrt{5x^2+10x+14}=4-2x-x^2$$
>
> then the same approach leads to
>
> $$\sqrt{3t+4}+\sqrt{5t+9}=5-t$$
>
> which also features a strictly increasing left hand side and a
>   strictly decreasing right hand side, so can have at most one real
>   solution.  But in this case it's easy to see that $t=0$ is a solution,
>   so we conclude that $t=0$ is the *only* real solution, which gives
>   $x=-1$ as the only real solution of the original (altered) equation.
>
> **End of digression.**

For the equation $\sqrt{3t+4}+\sqrt{5t-1}=5-t$, unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any simple solution as in the digression; if you do the algebra of repeated squarings, you get the ugly quartic

$$t^4-36t^3+308t^2-860t+500=0$$

which, according to Wolfram Alpha, doesn't seem to factor nicely.  It does, though, have just one real root in the requisite range, $t\approx0.77971$, from which we get $x=-1\pm\sqrt t\approx-1\pm0.883$.

In my opinion, if this was meant to be a preparation problem for a math competition, then there was a typo, changing the number $14$, as in the digression above, into a $4$.  The problem as stated can, as I've indicated, be solved numerically, but it's messy and tedious and not the sort of thing one would expect in a competition.

Comment: Yep, that's the answer my professor gave. Thanks!

Comment: @AksharGandhi Did he used the computer ? How he calculated $$t^4-36t^3+308t^2-860t+500=0$$

Comment: @AakashKumar, the first squaring, to $3t+4+2\sqrt{(3t+4)(5t-1)}+5t-1=25-10t+t^2$, hardly requires a computer, nor does rewriting it as $2\sqrt{15t^2+17t-4}=t^2-18t+22$.  The second squaring, to $60t^2+68t-16=(t^2-18t+22)^2=t^4-36t^3+368t^2-792t+484$, benefits from modern technology in expanding the trinomial, but could be done by hand in a pinch.  Finding the roots of the quartic, however, is, these days, best relegated to the computer.

Comment: @BarryCipra Expanding in not a problem , find a root of quartic is a problem specially when roots are not integer , question type this will never come in competitive exam unless some help is provided.

Answer (score -1):

The main question is :-

Solve for x
:-
$(\sqrt{3x^2+6x+7} + \sqrt{5x^2+10x+4})=4−2x−x^2$

assume

$t_1=\sqrt{3x^2+6x+7}$

$t_2=\sqrt{5x^2+10x+4}$

when simplified, gives,

${{t_1}^2 + {t_2}^2 + 2t_1t_2} = x^4 + 4 x^3 - 4 x^2 - 16 x + 16
$

$3x^2+6x+7 + 5x^2+10x+4 + 2\sqrt{{(3x^2+6x+7)}{(5x^2+10x+4)}} = x^4 + 4 x^3 - 4 x^2 - 16 x + 16$

$8x^2 +16x + 11 + 2\sqrt{28 + 94 x + 107 x^2 + 60 x^3 + 15 x^4} = x^4 + 4 x^3 - 4 x^2 - 16 x + 16$

$-x^4 -4x^3 + 12x^2 + 32x - 5 +2\sqrt{28 + 94 x + 107 x^2 + 60 x^3 + 15 x^4} = 0$

By Plotting this on a graph we find that this is a discontinuous function :
[image]

Hence, the Roots of this COMPLEX polynomial are:

$x \approx -1.9929$

$x \approx -0.0071487$

$x \approx -5.5743$

$x \approx 3.5743$

Root plot :

[image]

Thank you!